# if value x == any value in list y: python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm relatively new to python and want to do something like:

```
if value x == any value in list y:
   write x
```

this would operate wihtin a function, so only solutions which match a certain criteria would write to csv as they are generated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> x = 8
>>> if x in (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55):
        print('x is an early Fibonacci number')
x is an early Fibonacci number
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use the in syntax:

```
if x in ["a", "b", "c"]
   ... do stuff
```

And also if you care about the number of occurances of x you may use count:

```
if y.count(x) == 1
  ... do stuff
```

Comment: @Don If you are only interested in the existence of an item in a list, `count` will be slower, as it will need to go over *every* list item.

Comment: @poke that is why I said `in` is the better option, but also mention that you if you need the actual number of occurrences you should use count.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
x = somevalue
y = somelist
if x in y:
    print x  #not sure if this is what you mean by 'write'
```